# What is the difference between (10, 10, 10) and 10 10 10 in Shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, tuples

I defined
`a=b=c=10` in Shell

and just typed
`a,b,c` and got `(10, 10, 10)`.

But I when I type
`print(a,b,c)`, it returns `10 10 10`.

What is the difference between these two?
I know the former is a tuple and the latter is int.

Comment: `(a,b,c)` is putting three values in a tuple. `print(a,b,c)` is passing three arguments to `print`, which then prints each of them.

Comment: If you want to pass a tuple in a function call, then you will need to include the outer parentheses explicitly to distinguish it from multiple parameters: `print((a, b, c))`. In many other contexts, it is permitted to omit the outer parentheses, as in your earlier `a, b, c` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell, when you use `a,b,c` it is actually representing a tuple, and the `repr()` of that is printed in the shell, but when run as an actual python script it will not be printed. It is separated by a comma because it is tuple, and this is how it’s represented. You could even try `print((a,b,c))` and since it’s a tuple, it will print `(10,10,10)` as is the return value of `str()`.

On the other hand `print()` accepts any number of arguments, in this case you used `print(a,b,c)` these arguments will be printed (calling the `str()` method), separated by a space, unless the `sep` parameter is specified to separate them using another character, a space is the default. Therefore, if variables a, b and c contains 10, the print function will print `10 10 10`, which is separated by a space.